# dateTimePicker1.Value < dateTimePicker2.Value = true when values are identical on runtime

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I have dateTimePicker1 and dateTimePicker2 controls loading on Form1. They both have the same date and time on load.

```
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
        dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
```

When I check if they have different values using

```
if (dateTimePicker1.Value < dateTimePicker2.Value) {
    Console.WriteLine(dateTimePicker1.Value + " is earlier than " + dateTimePicker2.Value);
}
```

the statement returns **true** and writes to the console. This is not what I would expect. I would expect this to return false.

If I increase each control's value by 1 second, causing them to still match, the statement returns **false** as expected and nothing is written to the console.

Why does the less than evaluation return true on load when both values are identical?

Comment: Check the Ticks and/or the Millisecond properties of the Value property.  I am guessing the DateTimes are not really equal.

Comment: how do you set date times?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing about Ticks / Millisecond properties and that they aren't really equal.. I did research that, but I'm not sure how to make the two values equal on load.

Comment: Do subtraction and look at the resulting TimeSpan. I guarantee you'll see a difference.

Comment: try to set datetimepicker1 , then assign it to datetimepicker2. `datetimepicker2=datetimepicker1`.

Comment: Well that was obvious! Derp! The answer, then is twofold. 1. The time populated by each control happens in chronological order down to the very tick of time that it loads in. 2. Controls will load at two different times. Make one equal to the other on load.

Comment: i also forget simple things sometimes. it happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not know how you are loading the values. But, depending on what precision you are looking for (eg. in hours, minutes or second) you can subtract the two values and compare. Example: If you need precision in seconds then you can do something similar to below:

```
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
        dateTimePicker2.Value = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(999);
        var timeSpan1 = dateTimePicker1.Value - dateTimePicker2.Value;
        if (Math.Abs(timeSpan1.TotalSeconds) > 1) {
            MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value + " is not same as " + dateTimePicker2.Value);
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value + " is same as " + dateTimePicker2.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given by setting the two values equal to each other on load. This is because the controls load at different times. They are not really equal.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    }
```

I'm not sure how to give credit here, it belongs to two commenters.